# How to put the output of Get items into a excel sheet in Microsoft Power Automate?

Tags: openapi, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am making a flow in Microsoft Power Automate which goes as follows:

1. Manual Trigger
2. Get items (from sharepoint)

Now this flow works just fine. But I want to put the output from the get items into an excel sheet.  How should I do that?

I have already tried using the add row in the table action but it gives an error.
This is the error message:

> ResponseSwaggerSchemaValidationFailure The API 'sharepointonline' returned an invalid response for workflow operation 'Get_items' of type 'OpenApiConnection'. Error details: 'The API operation 'GetItems' is missing required property 'body/value/88/Field'.

How to fix this and achieve the result? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: So show your flow.

Comment: @Skin I have mentioned the flow since I am unable to add an image. But there are just those 2 blocks. Need help on what to do further.